# Breaking down the sentence "This is my pen"

Tags: nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech

In the above sentence...
1) Is "This" pronoun or demonstrative adjective?
2) Is "my" the adjective(if yes, which kind)?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you have broken down the sentence, can you put it back together and state the rules followed? Otherwise you just leave sentence shards all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

- **This** is a pronoun, and is the *subject* of the sentence. It's not an adjective; if it were, it would be placed in the sentence like "this pen."
- **my** is a *possessive* adjective. It modifies the noun "pen."

This is a very basic sentence; have you visited the [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site? You might find questions and answers there that are more appropriate for you.